# Crop then center and zoom

Tags: video-editor, editing

My video is 1080p HD, shot with GoPro. Using GoPro Studio I have removed the fisheye effect and exported it in AVI format.

Using Pinnacle 17 (or another tool, but this one has to be free), I want to crop some part of the entire image, then zoom it (a little), then center it above another clip.

I don't know how to do this. I've tried effects in "media editor" but so far I only ended with standalone pictures.

Comment: Which version of Pinnacle Studio do you have.  If it is plus or better, you can use the same technique as covered in [this answer](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/8651/final-cut-pro-x-ken-burn-effect-on-video-clips-with-out-cutting-clip-apart).  Keyframe animation is the general way to accomplish this.  If you don't need it animated, it would just be a simple scale and crop operation.  I don't know where exactly the parameters are in Pinnacle studio, but they should be fairly easy unless the software is really bad.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I found another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Picture in Picture to display my orginal video, cropped, zoomed and where I want above another picture or video.